# UIImageview moving position on screen from storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, xcode-storyboard

I have a storyboard with a UIImageView on it.

When I load the app in the emulator the UIImageView has a different position.

What could be causing this? The only thing I am doing to the UIImageview in the code is making it a subview of another UIImageview.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to make it a subview?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your storyboard is for the iPhone 5 and not for the iPhone 4 screen.

You can turn this off by clicking on the icon at the bottom of the storyboard screen. It's the left icon in the icon group.

Hope that it's the answer on your question

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Autolayout ? If not , then probably your struts and springs of the UIImageView are not set correctly causing the ImageView to change position.